# Javascript | Run function if HTML5 players is going to be used, don't run if Flash Player is avaiable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a JS function only if HTML5 player is going to be used (I am using JWPlayer), I have been reading and I don't find a Javascript event that tell me when this is happening.

I want this function to run if HTML5 player is going to be used (If user is on an Ipad/Android/etc), if it's on Desktop I want to ignore this function.

Thanks

Comment: Who wants to use Flash when you have HTML5 or Silverlight? But seriously use `return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType` It tells you if HTML5 video is supported.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#setup

> **Setup**
> These API calls are used to setup players and learn when and with which technology players are instantiated.
>
> **getRenderingMode()**
> Returns the rendering mode in which the player is setup. Can be **flash** or **html5**.